# FCM : Handling different data notification of an android app when app is in foreground

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am sending 2 different  data notifications in my app using cloud functions.

when I received the 1st notification in app and taps on notification it redirects to the my intended page using pendingIntent.

Now when I received the 2nd notification in app and taps on notification how to redirects to another activity(sent Invitation page). How to implement this .

**my firebasemessaging class**

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "MY android fcm service";
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
      String docId ;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        String FirstName = "0";
        String Amount = "0";
        String SenderID1 = "0";
        String ReceiverId1 ="0";
        String ReceiverPhoneNumberst="0";
        String SenderAutoId="0";


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            FirstName = remoteMessage.getData().get("Name");
            Amount = remoteMessage.getData().get("Amount");
            SenderID1=remoteMessage.getData().get("SenderID");
            System.out.println("Senderid"+SenderID1);
            ReceiverId1=remoteMessage.getData().get("ReceiverId");
            ReceiverPhoneNumberst=remoteMessage.getData().get("ReceiverPhoneNumber");
            long ReceiverPhoneNumber = Long.parseLong(ReceiverPhoneNumberst);
            SenderAutoId=remoteMessage.getData().get("SenderAutoId");
            Map<String,Object> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put("SenderName",FirstName);
            data.put("Amount",Amount);
            data.put("SenderID",SenderID1);
            data.put("ReceiverId",ReceiverId1);
            data.put("ReceiverPhoneNumber",ReceiverPhoneNumber);
            data.put("SenderAutoId",SenderAutoId);

            final String finalAmount = Amount;
            final String finalFirstName = FirstName;
            db.collection("deyaPayUsers").document(mAuth.getUid().toString()).collection("Split").document(mAuth.getUid().toString()).collection("ReceivedInvitation").add(data).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {

                    docId = documentReference.getId();
                    Log.d(TAG,"DocumentSnapshot written with ID:" +docId);
                    //System.out.println("documentadded is docId"+ docId);

                    Log.d(TAG, "From:" + remoteMessage.getFrom());
                    Log.d(TAG, "Notification MessageBody:" + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
                    Log.d(TAG, "Notification data:" + remoteMessage.getData());
                    createNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), finalFirstName, finalAmount, docId);
                   // createNotification1(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());




                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w(TAG,"Error adding document",e);
                }
            });

        }
    }



    private void createNotification(String messageBody, String FirstName, String amount,String docId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent( this,ReceivedNotification.class );
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("FirstName",FirstName);
        System.out.println(FirstName);
        intent.putExtra("Amount",amount);
        intent.putExtra("DocumentId",docId);
        System.out.print("dDA "+docId);
        PendingIntent resultIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this , 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri notificationSoundURI = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("deyaPay")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true )
                .setSound(notificationSoundURI)
                .setContentIntent(resultIntent)
                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_player)
        // Add media control buttons that invoke intents in your media service
        //.addAction(R.drawable.accept, "Accept",) // #0
        //.addAction(R.drawable.ic_reject, "Reject", ResultActivity.class) ; // ;

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, mNotificationBuilder.build());


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the simple snippet
use a flag in the notification you push from the server.

when you receive notification in onMessageRecevied function extract that flag and pass it to sendNotification

```
    private void sendNotification(int flag, String title,String messageBody ) {
NotificationManager    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    long notificatioId = System.currentTimeMillis();


Intent intent=null;
   if(flag==1){
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activity1.class);
   }
   else{
         intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activity2.class);
   }

    intent.putExtra("fromItem",false);
    intent.putExtra("title", title);; // Here pass your activity where you want to redirect.

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) (Math.random() * 100), intent, 0);

    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        currentapiVersion = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
    } else{
        currentapiVersion = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(currentapiVersion)
            .setContentTitle(this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody))
            .setContentText(title)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setDefaults(Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify((int) notificatioId, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

In the server side code add the flag in the JSON message

```
 var data = new
            {

                to=deviceId,
                    notification = new
                    {
                        body = "\""+notificationMessage +"\"",
                        title = "\""+_title+"\"",
                        sound = "Enabled\""
                    }
                    ,
                    data=new {

                        flag= "\"" + _flag+"\"",
                        message= "\""+notificationMessage+"\"",
                        additional = "\"" + addtional+"\""

                    }




            };
```

this is the simple snippet for json packet

Comment: I need to add flag in server side

Comment: @LahariAreti add the flag in json packet

Comment: @LahariAreti  whatever you require for eg. flag=1 for your activityA and flag=2 for your activity2 (you need to decide which activity you need to open)

Comment: its ok can u help me one thing . I have 2 different message body By using that we can pass the intent classes right

Comment: @LahariAreti yes, only thing that you need to manage the json parsing in the OnMessage Receice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167781/discussion-between-lahari-areti-and-sunil-soni).

Answer (score 1):

You can't predefined it in `NotificationBuilder`, but you can do one thing you can create one common activity and route all notifications to this activity with some flag/type to recognise the notification type. From this activity you can redirect to your desired activity by checking the notification type you passed.

Answer (score 1):

Inside this function, change Intent according to messageBody,

```
private void createNotification(String messageBody, String FirstName, String amount,String docId) {

    Intent intent=null;
    if(messageBody.contains(“xyz”))
            intent = new Intent( this, ReceivedNotification.class );
    else
            intent = new Intent( this, SecondReceivedNotification.class );

    — — —

    PendingIntent resultIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this , 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

and pass it over to Pending Intent.

Comment: kk I will try it

Comment: what do u mean by xyz

Comment: I used these but it is going else part always